# Cannot assign amplify:ListDomainAssociations to USer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-amplify

I need to allow a developer to access AWS Amplify service with all the permissions except for Create, Delete and Update Domain Association. I have created the following policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "amplify:ListDomainAssociations",
                "amplify:CreateBranch",
                "amplify:ListBranches",
                "amplify:GetApp",
                "amplify:UpdateApp"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:26XXXXXXXXXX:apps/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "amplify:GetBranch",
                "amplify:ListJobs",
                "amplify:DeleteBranch",
                "amplify:UpdateBranch"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:26XXXXXXXXXX:apps/*/branches/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "amplify:GetJob",
                "amplify:GetDomainAssociation",
                "amplify:DeleteJob",
                "amplify:StartJob",
                "amplify:StopJob"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:26XXXXXXXXXX:apps/*/branches/*/jobs/*",
                "arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:26XXXXXXXXXX:apps/*/domains/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "amplify:CreateApp",
                "amplify:ListApps"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy has been generated using the visual editor.
As you can see I have `amplify:ListDomainAssociations` allowed on `arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:26XXXXXXXXXX:apps/*`

I attach the policy to the user but when he log into the AWS Console via Browser he got this error

`User: arn:aws:iam::26XXXXXXXXXX:user/tp_amplifyPermissionTest is not authorized to perform: amplify:ListDomainAssociations on resource: arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:26XXXXXXXXXX:user:/apps/d1xxxxxxxxxxxx/domains`

I see that there is a `/` right after the `:` in the resource name present inside the error message, and that `/` is not present in my policy arn resource name. So I tried to add that, allowing the `amplify:ListDomainAssociations` for the following resource `arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:26XXXXXXXXXX:/apps/*` but says that the `/` is unexpected and I cannot save it.

I have also tried to edit the Resources as following

```
"Resource": [
                "arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:26XXXXXXXXXX:apps/*",
                "arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:26XXXXXXXXXX:*"
            ]
```

But still no success.
Any idea where can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some confusion on AWS. Some `Resources` should be added with `:app`, others with `:/app`. Here how I have edited the policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "amplify:ListDomainAssociations",
                "amplify:CreateBranch",
                "amplify:ListBranches",
                "amplify:GetApp",
                "amplify:UpdateApp"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:26XXXXXXXXXX:apps/*",
                "arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:26XXXXXXXXXX:/apps/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "amplify:GetBranch",
                "amplify:ListJobs",
                "amplify:DeleteBranch",
                "amplify:UpdateBranch"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:26XXXXXXXXXX:apps/*/branches/*",
                "arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:26XXXXXXXXXX:/apps/*/branches/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "amplify:GetJob",
                "amplify:GetDomainAssociation",
                "amplify:DeleteJob",
                "amplify:StartJob",
                "amplify:StopJob"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:26XXXXXXXXXX:apps/*/branches/*/jobs/*",
                "arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:26XXXXXXXXXX:apps/*/domains/*",
                "arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:26XXXXXXXXXX:/apps/*/branches/*/jobs/*",
                "arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:26XXXXXXXXXX:/apps/*/domains/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor3",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "amplify:CreateApp",
                "amplify:ListApps"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This worked for me